# Character count C program not displaying count

Tags: c

I am currently learning the C language by coding along to '[The C Programming Language (2nd Edition)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3USQRUAFUPFSK&keywords=c%20programming&qid=1557605818&s=gateway&sprefix=C%20pro%2Caps%2C352&sr=8-1). The book features this program: [image] upon creation and compilation of this program everything seems to run smoothly: [image]but when i run the program, it doesn't seem to work:[image] why is this?

Comment: How are you sending the EOF character?

Comment: Because the program has no way of knowing that you have finished typing input unless you signal end of file.

Comment: To send an EOF from the keyboard: Ctrl-D on linux or mac, Ctrl-Z on windows.

Comment: You can either use `^D` to terminate terminal input, or you can redirect `stdin` from a file, e.g. `./character_counting < file.txt`

Comment: It does not print the number of characters typed until the loop has ended.